# How to ensure I have file all tax documents for 2022 as a first time filer?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I'm a nonresident alien for tax purposes - as per Sprintax. Usually, all the forms I need to file as a non-resident alien are provided in Sprintax, but I also created a Robinhood account. I have an insignificant profit from the stocks, and little interest because of Robinhood Gold yield (say less than $100). Recently, I also contributed to the 2022 Roth IRA which has a 1% match.

I figure I will have to file tax for Robihnhood besides other tax documents for W2, etc., but I'm just even more confused after a bunch of Google - maybe because I don't have experience with tax filing ever. What are some of the suggested ways to navigate what to file, and make sure I file the tax correctly?

Hopefully, this is not a duplicate. If it is, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where do you have a Roth IRA that gives a 1% _match_?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Robinhood

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you need to report your income and not your tax documents. So even if you got no tax documents, you still have to report your income correctly.

Tax documents make it easier, though, and easier to track.

The rule of thumb is that anyone paying you more than $600 for non-investment income, and more than $10 for investment income (interest and such) - should provide you with some version of a 1099 form (there are many: 1099-B for brokerages, 1099-DIV for dividends, 1099-INT for interest payments, 1099-NEC for earned income, 1099-MISC for other different income types, 1099-K from payment processors, 1099-G from governments, etc etc). Sometimes you'll get consolidated forms - brokerages usually combine the -B, -DIV and -INT versions into a single report provided to you.

For non-resident aliens you may get a 1042-S form in addition or instead of a 1099 form. You need the 1042-S form if any taxes were withheld at source.

Comment: This is correct for e-filing. But if you're paper filing, you must attach the federal copy of any W-2 and W-2G, and any 1099-R showing withholdings. States also may or may not require their copy.

Comment: @user71659 you must attach if you have them, but you still have to file a return even if you don't.

Comment: Filing with it missing is certainly better than not filing, but the [IRS instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#en_US_2022_publink1000106137) say if you're missing the docs, you need to get a replacement from the people who issued them.

Comment: @user71659 this is for W2 which the OP has. This is specifically important due to FICA taxes and SSA rights and coverage.

Comment: littleadv: nonresident tax status with US employment usually means student/scholar in visa categories F,J,M,Q and for school-related employment (usually the only kind authorized) those are NOT subject to FICA and don't get SS/Medicare credit. Moreover for people who _are_ covered, SSA receives the W2's directly from the employer, it doesn't get them from IRS. (In contrast SSA does get schedule SE forwarded by IRS for self-employed people.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ok... How is it relevant to the topic?

Comment: As far as I know, Robinhood (or banks or anyone who gives me the interest) should send me my tax forms. All I have right now is the W2 form, so there must be a lot more forms that aren't sent to me. It seems like I have to check all sources of income and contact all issuers to ask for those tax forms to get an exhaustive list of forms to file (hence the question), right?

Comment: @Elly *should* is a desire, *must* is a requirement. If there's not a requirement for them to send you something, what they *should* or *should not* do is up to them. Being you a non-resident alien, there may be no such requirement if no withholding was made. As I said - you don't need the forms to file your tax return.